# Apache server wont start after trying to configure it to run with php

Tags: php, apache

I installed apache server 2.2.19 on  a vista machine. It was running fine but I tried to configure it to use php by modifying the httpd.conf file. These are the lines I added

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
PHPIniDir “C:\PHP”
```

I added this below this line

```
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
```

I also  added this line

```
LoadModule php5_module “C:\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll”
```

I added this below this line

```
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

I tried to restart the apache server but every time i do so it returns an error message that The requested operation has failed. What could be the problem?

Comment: what do the logs say? they are usually stored within the Apache\logs directory...

Comment: Start with testing the configuration running `apachectl configtest`

Comment: I'd suggest downloading [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) for editing config files (or just regular notepad).

Comment: Am using vista but every time i try to test php by saving a file in htdocs it says i have insufficient priviledges. how do i go around this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don´t have any experience with installing it on windows, but the following lines seem very wrong to me:

```
PHPIniDir “C:\PHP”
LoadModule php5_module “C:\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll”
```

Is that really what you added? If it is, I would suggest changing it to:

```
PHPIniDir "C:\PHP"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Note that I am using `"` instead of the curly quotes you are using.

Comment: Good catch on that.  Maybe he isn't editing the file in notepad.

Comment: That's a very good catch.  And, if s/he didn't then it raises the question, "why wasn't the config copy/pasted directly from the setup?"

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems I would suggest just downloading [Xampp for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).  It takes the manual steps out of installing the separate components.

Comment: too bad you can never upgrade xampp

Answer (score 1):

Normaly, this is how you would set up PHP under Apache...

(adjust for your paths)

```
LoadFile "D:/WampDeveloper/Components/Php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "D:/WampDeveloper/Components/Php/php5apache2_2.dll

<IfModule php5_module>

PHPIniDir "D:/WampDeveloper/Config/Php"

    <Directory "D:/WampDeveloper/Websites/*/webroot">
        AddType text/html .php .php4 .php5 .phps
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .php5
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

You will do better to use a pre-made Apache, PHP, and MySQL solution for Windows.

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

[WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper)